# Open images from Windows store application

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I have created a windows store application and I want the user to open Documents, Excel files and picture from the app. I want the files to open in their default application. i.e. Docs in word and pictures in windows picture viewer.

I have used the following code:

```
FileOpenPicker openPicker = new FileOpenPicker();
openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".Doc");
openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".Docx");
openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".png");
openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpg");

StorageFile file = await openPicker.PickSingleFileAsync();

if (file!=null)
{
    await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchFileAsync(file);
}
```

When I run this and browse to a word document the file opens up fine using word, great.

But if I browse to an image file, it doesn't do anything. I don't get any errors.

Any ideas what I need to do?

Thanks

Comment: I suspect there is no launcher set for the image files.

Comment: No because it opens fine when I open it via windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One other thing you can do is to force app picker if default program could not be launched like following:

```
if (file != null)
{
    var options = new Windows.System.LauncherOptions();
    options.DisplayApplicationPicker = true;
    bool success = await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchFileAsync(file, options);                
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no error and, simply, nothing happens? That's strange.

Here's my go-to syntax, but it's basically yours:

[image]

Let's consider what should happen. When you "launch" a docx you are basically asking the default viewer to open for that file, in that case Word. With an image you are asking the image viewer to launch. Should it work? Yes.

Launching a docx when Word is not installed should not result in the behavior your are seeing. No. You should get prompted to find a viewer in the Store. Same with an image. Even without a viewer you should get something.

Not to be a dork here, but have you rebooted? It really sounds more like something strange has happened. You might also try appending "file:///" to the front of the URL to perhaps invoke the file viewer more explicitly. None of that should be necessary however.

Best of luck